# Rails 4 - images not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails project. I am currently setting up email functionality, and am testing it. I am using [letter opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener), haml, and using one of Mailchimp's [email templates](https://github.com/mailchimp/Email-Blueprints).

I am currently using an image_tag to link to an image that I would like to display.

When it is written like this;

```
= image_tag 'my_image.png', id: 'headerImage', :style => "max-width:600px;", "mc:allowdesigner" => "", "mc:allowtext" => "", "mc:edit" => "header_image", "mc:label" => "header_image", :alt => 'alt text'
```

I get the broken image in the html. When it is written like this;

```
= image_tag 'my_image', id: 'headerImage', :style => "max-width:600px;", "mc:allowdesigner" => "", "mc:allowtext" => "", "mc:edit" => "header_image", "mc:label" => "header_image", :alt => 'alt text'
```

I get

`Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( my_image ) to config/initializers/assets.rb and restart your server`

my assets.rb looks like this;

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( my_image )` and I restarted the server. I have also tried manually linking the image using relative paths, and nothing seems to work. I have also ran `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` and still nothing.

I have not had this problem before, but it seems like rails just does not want to display this image. Maybe it is something related to `letter_opener`?

If anyone else has experienced this strange problem and knows what to do, or how they fixed it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which folder is `my_image.png` file in?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy `my_image.png` is in the assets folder along with all my other images

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the latest version of sprockets that has been giving developers this problem.  Try downgrading the `sprokets-rails` gem.  Put this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.3.3'
```

Then do `bundle update sprockets-rails`.